# Analysis recursion limit convergence proof

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ be given, and define a sequence $(X_n)_{n≥1}$ recursively by setting  $X_1 = c$ and $X_{n+1} = f(X_n)$ for every $n ≥ 1$. Assume that $(X_n)_{n≥1}$ converges to a limit $L$. Prove that $f(L) = L$.

Can someone help me with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definition of a continuous function is that if $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = x$ then $f( \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}) = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_{n})$. Then

$$f(L) = f(\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n}) = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} f(X_n) = \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n+1} = L$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(X_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}X_{n+1}$

If that’s not enough, a nearly complete solution is spoiler-protected below, but try to get it from the hint.

> $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(X_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(X_n)$$

Comment: thanks! yeah the hint helped!

Comment: @user67208: Excellent. You’re welcome!